# What is wrong with this string reverser I wrote in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

I've seen similar things(changes in the variables) that work but this one doesn't canyou guys tell me why?
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,j,k;
    char str[255],rvrs[255];

    printf("Insert your string: ");
    gets(str);

    i=strlen(str);
    k=i;

    for(j=0;j<=i;j++,k--){
        rvrs[k]=str[j];
    }

    printf("%s",rvrs);
}
```

Comment: First, please tell us what "doesn't work". And the input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: See what is [Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first

Comment: A number of people will complain that you tagged this both C and C++, although they are separate languages. I would like to ask: Why did you do this? Do you think of them as one language? Do you think anything in C++ should be automatically C as well, or vice-versa? Do you want one answer for both or two answers, one for each?

Comment: In a string, the chars are indexed from *0* to `strlen()` **- 1**.

Comment: Perhaps it's like Java and Javascript. The later is like the former but script :/

Comment: Function `gets` is obsolete.

Comment: Array indexing. `k=i; for(j=0;j<=i;j++,k--)` should be `k = i - 1; for(j = 0; j < k; j++, k--)` so the string will not be reversed twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The code as written copies the string in reverse to a new array. It will not do anything twice. You are thinking of reversing by swapping elements within one array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil agree, but the end index is off by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last iteration of the loop, `j` equals `i`. `str[i]` is the null character (`str[0]` through `str[i-1]` are the `i` non-null characters in the string). So, in this last iteration, `rvrs[k]` is set to the null character. And, at this point, `k` is zero. Therefore, `rvrs` contains an empty string (a string in which the null character is the first character, so the string ends with no non-null characters).

To fix this, you need to modify your code:

- First, set `rvrs[i]` to zero, so that it will be terminated in the place you want it to be.
- Second, modify the loop to properly reverse the elements from `0` to `i-1`, not from `0` to `i`. Take care to ensure `k` has the proper value while doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was really clueless about all that. And I only tagged c++ because i need five tags and i didn't know what else to put

Comment: @DavidMachado: Five tags is an upper limit, not a requirement.

Comment: Then I misunderstood it. this is so embarassing sorry

Comment: @DavidMachado: Not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

With `j<=strlen(str)`, you reverse the strings including the string termination character. Thereby, the first character of `rvrs` will be the string termination character, meaning that `rvrs` will be/behave as an "empty" string.

Instead, you'd reverse everything between indizes `0..strlen(str)-1`, and you should terminate `rvrs` at position `rvrs[strlen(str)]='\0'`.

BTW: Note that `gets` is obsolete/deprecated. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Use for example the standard function `fgets`.

When `j` is equal to `i` that in turn is equal to `strlen(str)` then `str[j]` is equal to '\0'. That is the terminating zero is written in the beginning of the array `rvrs`

```
rvrs[k]=str[j];
```

that does not make sense.

Take into account that the function `strlen` has return type `size_t` not `int`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   255

int main(void) 
{
    char str[N], rvrs[N];
    str[0] = '\0';

    printf("Insert your string: ");
    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    size_t n = strcspn( str, "\n" );

    for ( size_t j = 0; j != n; j++ )
    {
        rvrs[j] = str[n - j - 1];
    }

    rvrs[n] = '\0';

    puts( rvrs );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
Insert your string: Hello David Machado
odahcaM divaD olleH
```